# Comparing non-nested cox regression models

Tags: predictive-models, cox-model

I'm trying to see if a new variable adding in a prediction model is better than the old model.
Therefore I've made 3 cox regression models, based on backwards stepwise regression.

So I got models:

1. Variables X,Y
2. Variables Q,Z
3. Variables X,Y,Q,Z

To compare the additive value of Q and Z on top of X and Y, I had a look at the C-statistic, AIC and BIC. All of these indicators show model 3 is the best. Now I'm trying to see if model 3 is a statistically significant better prediction model than 1 and 2. For this; I've read in the literature that I  should use a deLong's test. However, I did not manage to do this, because I cannot get the AUC's out of the cox-regression model.

To continue; is the way I see the above correct? Nex; how can I compare non-nested cox regression models?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to see if model 3 is a statistically significant better prediction model than 1 and 2.

It doesn't have to be "a statistically significant better prediction model" for you to use it in preference to the others. Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) emphasize the futility of depending on *p*-values to decide on what predictors to keep in a predictive model. Unless the model is over-fit, you can (and often, should) keep "non-significant" predictors in your model to maintain performance. See Harrell's brief but highly informative answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89217/28500).

In your case you already have information about the superiority of model 3, via the AIC and its basis in likelihood. Harrell considers that  a "[gold standard](https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/)" for predictive value. You also could do direct likelihood-ratio tests of model 3 against model 1 and  of model 3 against model 2, as those are both nested comparisons.

There is some dispute about the use of AIC for non-nested models; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116935/28500) and its links for discussion. You might want to think about *why* you want to compare non-nested models directly in the first place. If you have a useful predictive model but need more parsimony in your number of predictors, simple backward elimination will lead to a set of nested models. You should only get non-nested models if you allowed a combination of backward and forward predictor selection.

The C-index is closely related to an AUC. Neither provides a very sensitive basis for comparing models.

Comment: Dear EdM, 
Thanks for you answer! So, as you indicate the way I did it now is already 'sufficient'. Can I concluded based on this data, that if variable X is in the best model (model 3), on top of all the others, has a good predictive value and should be considered in prediction models?

Comment: @KeesvanBergeijk from what you show model 3 seems to be the best, so you should include all 4 of its predictors including X. The only caution is whether there might be overfitting. AIC tends to correct for overfitting, but rechecking with bootstrapping can be wise. This [Harrell blog page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116935/28500) shows how to use a likelihood ratio to estimate the relative explained variation attributable to a specific predictor or set of predictors, if you want to estimate how much X adds to the model.